# PHP, Can't access base class via child properly

Tags: php, oop

Base Class:

```
class A {

    public x;
    public y;

    public function __construct {

        $this->x = new X();
        $this->y = new Y();
    }
}
```

Class `X`:

```
class X extends A {

    public function __construct {}

    public function job() {

        echo 'x working!';
    }
}
```

Class `Y`:

```
class Y extends A {

    public function __construct {}

    public function job() {

        var_dump($this->x);    // NULL, Why???

        $this->x->job();
    }
}
```

**Problem**: When I'm calling `x->job()` from inside of class `Y`, I have no access to the `X` already instanced object totally, and `var_dump` shows it's `null`.

Any ideas what's wrong with that?

Thanks! :)

**Update:**

If I use `parent::__construct();` in the child class' `__construct()` method, then it would generates `Fatal Error: maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`. That's why I add those empty `__construct()` methods. Any idea again how to solve that?

I have this one also on the source code:

```
$base = new A();
```

So, the constructor should been run already, right?

Comment: You need to explicitly instantiate the parent with `parent::__construct();`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you have to call the constructor of a base class in php from the extended class via parent::__construct();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call `parent::__construct()` in the chil class constructor, otherwise the parent constructor is not called and the property won't recieve its value.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you call the parent constructor, you will call `new X()` which will start doing all sorts of recursive things. I think your whole model might be a bit flawed. An `X` object is an `A` object that has an `X` object that is an `A`...

Comment: yeah, you're right ... any idea to find the same approach, but a working one?

Comment: @Mahdi, don't create those sub-objects through the constructor at all. Instead create a separate method to do that, and call that method after you've created your 'root' object.

Answer (score 1):

In this example case you could also just leave out the constructor of the child class, because it doesn't do anything, else use the suggested method by GolezTrol

Comment: The child class constructor may be the most suitable place to call the parent constructor method though.

Comment: for code clarity it might be good yes, though it would not have any meaning.